# Bitwise Operators in practical terms

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I understand how bitwise operators like >>, <<, >>> work on low level bits.
But i want to understand what they really are gonna do when someone write a code using them.
Like

```
 a << 2 = a * (2^2)
 a >> 2 = a / (2^2)
 ~ a = -(a) + (-1)
```

But i have no idea what >>>, &, | and ^ do.
Can anyone help me out.

Comment: If you Google [`java bitwise operators`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+bitwise+operators&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), top link is [The Java™ Tutorials - Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), and that explains all of them.

Comment: I understand bitwise operators, that's not my actual question. What i am really interested in knowing is what is actually happening. Like i mentioned a << b in plain english mean -> a multiplies by 2 raised to the power of b. What happens in the background is not my concern at the moment (actually i understand that part).

Comment: I should have provided the header as
Mathematical equivalents of bitwise operator

Answer (score 1):

The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand.

The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a **zero into the leftmost** position, while the leftmost position after ">>" **depends on sign extension**.

The bitwise & operator performs a bitwise AND operation.

The bitwise ^ operator performs a bitwise exclusive OR operation.

The bitwise | operator performs a bitwise inclusive OR operation.

[Code example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm)

[Logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate)

[Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

[See more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

For the example: a << 2 = a * (2^2);//it won't compilable in JAVA.

Comment: I think the quoted lines were taken from an guide attempting to show the relation of bit operations with arithmetic operations; and not actual code. And I think a better introductory resource is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: @Lars - Exactly what i want.